# Converting predefined quarter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am having small problem. I have a practice data frame (still learning) with coulmn which has year and quarters per-defined like so

```
 Date       Column2      Column3
   2004 Q-1    Other data   Other data
   2004 Q-2    Other Data   Other data
```

up to 2019. Pandas sees this as object, and I have been trying to convert it to date and quarter.

I have tried:

`df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace(' Q-', '').astype(int)` which gave error

`invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2019 4'`

`df['Date'] = df.ddate.dt.to_period("Q")` but my df doesn't have ddate attribute

`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y %q')`  with error:

`'q' is a bad directive in format '%Y %q'`

I am currently out of ideas of how to convert this so pandas can read this as quarters per year.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I like how clear your question is and you show everything you've tried! Perhaps you can figure out your problem with help of the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html If you do please post your own answer so others can learn.

Comment: I did try pandas docs first, and I did try a variation of DateTimeIndex. Just didn't remember it while I was writing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't as explicit. Do you want the date extracted from year quarter? Looks to me thats likely. If it is, please my attempt below. If aint, clarify to get help. Staggered it to be readable (I am a readable code enthusiast, like to demistify coding :-) );

```
data['Date'] = data['Date'].str.replace(r'-','')
```

[image]

```
data['Date'] = data['Date'].str.replace(' ',r'')
```

[image]

```
data['Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
```

[image]

If wanted EndMonth:

```
data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
data['EndMonth']= data.index.to_period('M').to_timestamp('M')
```

[image]

Comment: I am actually fine by having the quarters and the year together in one column. I don't need the end month. Thank you for the help.

Comment: This worked like a charm, but why do you use "r" in str.replace? `str.replace(r'-', '')` and `str.replace(' ', r'')`

Comment: r indicates a raw string in python strings. backslash indicates special characters. print('-\t>\t*') #for instance in this case in python t indicates tab,Please try it  out!!. t is not printed because t is a special character. If we make it print(r'-\t>\t*'), t gets printed because we told python this is a raw string